# Block Explorer, which fields are reversed, and which are the same as in a raw block dump?

Tags: protocol, websites, raw-data

Recently I'm trying to [properly recreate the genesis block in my low-level application](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=52706.0). To do this, I use [the Block Explorer to get the proper values for different fields](http://blockexplorer.com/rawblock/000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f), but at times it can be very confusing with its endianness. Which fields presented in the Block Explorer should be reversed before they are included in a raw block, and which should stay as they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashes are displayed in little-endian when they are actually big-endian on the network, and difficulty bits are displayed as big-endian when they are actually little-endian on the network.

All other integers are little-endian.